# How to place braces below a tree in tikz using relative coordinates (as opposed to hard-coded lengths)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-node

I'd like to place curly braces below the branches of a tree. The example below
does exactly that, but hard-coded values for the placement of the labels "Toss 1" and "Toss 2" are not ideal as they need to be adjusted when the paper/text size
changes etc. Is there any way to use relative coordinates/nodes to place
the two labels in a more robust way without the need of hard-coded lengths
(or at least only one such length, the vertical distance from the two labels
to the tree, say)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 0.25mm, grow=right, sloped,
      level 1/.style={level distance=1.8cm, sibling distance=2.4cm},
      level 2/.style={level distance=2.1cm, sibling distance=1.2cm},
      edge from parent/.style={draw, shorten >=1.4mm, shorten <=1.4mm},
      mynodestyle/.style={inner sep=1mm},
      myleafstyle/.style={inner sep=0mm}
      ]
      \node[mynodestyle] (root) {Coin toss}
      child {
        node[mynodestyle] (toss1) {$T$}
        child {
          node[myleafstyle, coordinate, label={[xshift=-1mm]right: $(T,T)$}] (toss2) {}
          edge from parent
          node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
        }
        child {
          node[myleafstyle, coordinate, label={[xshift=-1mm]right: $(T,H)$}] {}
          edge from parent
          node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
        }
        edge from parent
        node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
      }
      child {
        node[mynodestyle] {$H$}
        child {
          node[myleafstyle, coordinate, label={[xshift=-1mm]right: $(H,T)$}] {}
          edge from parent
          node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
        }
        child {
          node[myleafstyle, coordinate, label={[xshift=-1mm]right: $(H,H)$}] {}
          edge from parent
          node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
        }
        edge from parent
        node[above] {\tiny $1/2$}
      };
      % Labels. How to place the curly braces below the branches labeled with 1/2
      %         in terms of nodes/relative coordinates instead of hard-coded lengths?
      % Label "Toss 2"
      \node[coordinate, below right = 6.2mm and 1mm of toss1] (A2) {};% hard-coded
      \node[coordinate, below left  = 2.6mm and 1mm of toss2] (E2) {};% hard-coded
      \draw[decorate, decoration = {brace, mirror, amplitude = 2mm}] (A2)--node[below = 2mm, anchor = north] {Toss 2} (E2);
      % Label "Toss 1"
      \node[coordinate, below right = 18.2mm and -4mm of root] (A1) {};% hard-coded
      \node[coordinate, below left  =  6.2mm and 1mm of toss1] (E1) {};% hard-coded
      \draw[decorate, decoration = {brace, mirror, amplitude = 2mm}] (A1)--node[below = 2mm, anchor = north] {Toss 1} (E1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In comparison to your MWE, I add `calligraphy` library (for more fancy braces) and rename nodes. For position of brace anchors are used perpendicular coordinate.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                    calligraphy}    % new, had to be load after decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    BC/.style = {decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        raise=1mm,
        mirror},% for mirroring of brace
        ultra thick,
        pen colour=red % select color according to your taste
        },
%
grow=right,
level distance=2.2cm,  
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=2.4cm},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=1.2cm},
edge from parent/.style={draw,thick, shorten >=1.4mm, shorten <=1.4mm},
      N/.style = {inner sep=1pt},
      L/.style = {font=\tiny, above, sloped}
      ]
\node[N] (A) {Coin toss}
    child {node[N] (B) {$T$}
        child {node[N] (C) {$(T,T)$} 
        edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
              }
        child {node[N] {$(T,H)$}
        edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
              }
        edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
      }
    child {node[N] {$H$}
        child {node[N]  {$(H,T)$}
          edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
        }
        child {node[N]  {$(H,H)$}
          edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
        }
        edge from parent node[L] {$1/2$}
      };
%
\draw[BC] (A.330  |- C.south) -- node[below=8pt] {Toss 1} (B.west |- C.south);
\draw[BC] (B.east |- C.south) -- node[below=8pt] {Toss 2} (C.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Code for tree can be more concise and clear with use of the `forest` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}    %had to be loaded after decorations.pathreplacing
\tikzset{
 BC/.style = {% Brace Calligraphic
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        raise=2pt,
        mirror},% for mirroring of brace
        ultra thick,
        pen colour=red % select color according to your taste
        },
ELS/.style = {%Edge Label Style
              font=\scriptsize, sloped, pos=0.6,
              inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1}
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% tree
    grow = east,
    edge = {thick}, 
   l sep = 12mm,
   s sep =  4mm,
L/.style = {if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=north]{$1/2$}}}
                  {edge label={node[ELS=south]{$1/2$}}}} % since all labels are the same
        }
[Coin toss, name=A
    [$T$, name=B, L
        [{$(T,T)$}, name=C, L]
        [{$(T,H)$},L]
    ]
    [$H$, L
        [{$(H,T)$},L]
        [{$(H,H)$},L]
    ]
]
%
\draw[BC] (A.330  |- C.south) -- node[below=8pt] {Toss 1} (B.west |- C.south);
\draw[BC] (B.east |- C.south) -- node[below=8pt] {Toss 2} (C.south west);
    \end{forest}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In the case, that you like to have all edge labels above edge, than replace

```
L/.style = {if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=north]{$1/2$}}}
                  {edge label={node[ELS=south]{$1/2$}}}}
```

with

```
L/.style = {edge label={node[font=\scriptsize, sloped, pos=0.6,
                             inner sep=2pt, anchor=south]{$1/2$}}}
```

and delete definition of ELS style in `\tikzset`.

I prefer solution shown in above image.

Comment: Thanks, Zarko, exactly what I was looking for. As explanation, one only needs to manually adjust `raise=1mm`, the `330` in `A.330`, and the `below=8pt` to place the curly braces in the desired spot. Small comment: The `node distance = 2mm and 0mm` had no effect for me.

Comment: @MariusHofert, regarding `node distance` are forgotten from the first test. Now are superfluous. I will delete it ASAP.

Comment: What is the `330` in `A.330` exactly doing? In your example it changes the length of the first brace. In another example I'd like to change that length but changing the `330` seems to have no effect.

Comment: @MariusHofert, define anchor on node's border. It is positioned about point where edge from root node start. Value is determined by trials.

Comment: One disadvantage (with a tree with tree levels) I realized is that one cannot properly place the braces. I can define a `BC` style for each of the braces and adjust their lengths with `pre length` and `post length`, but if I do that to perfectly place the beginning and end of a brace below its tree branch, then the label ("Toss ...") is not centered below the brace anymore if `pre length` differs from `post length`.

Comment: @MariusHofert, I do not understand, what you mean with defining of braces. For them MWE has defined style for all braces in the image, so you not need to define it separately.  This is big advantages, all braces, regardless on their lengths, has the same style. Regarding  `pre length` and `post length`: in your case they are not essential and can be omitted (consequently braces will be for their lengths wider). What problem you have with braces? If you not liked them, you can use your definition for them for each braces and with them degrade a short and clean code proposed in solution.

Comment: @MariusHofert, see addendum to answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the misalignment I explained seems to come from the fact that the edge labels (here: 1/2) reach beyond the edges in the case I had in mind. This should be avoided anyways but I didn't immediately spot it as the labels just extended slightly beyond the edges in my example.